# Human agent handoff from a Microsoft Teams chatbot

Tags: azure, dialogflow-es, microsoft-teams

I built a chatbot using Dialogflow ES and integrate it with Microsoft Teams, now my bot is working well in Teams. If my bot fails to answer sometimes then I want to handover the conversation to human agent. How can I connect to a live agent from Microsoft Teams chatbot, is there any platform available to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a sample FAQ bot which is a friendly Q&A bot that brings a human in the loop when it is unable to help. Please check the following links - [FAQ Plus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/app-templates#faq-plus) and [microsoft-teams-apps-faqplus](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-faqplus)

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer from the comment section:

There is a sample FAQ bot which is a friendly Q&A bot that brings a human in the loop when it is unable to help. Please check the following links - [FAQ Plus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/app-templates#faq-plus) and [microsoft-teams-apps-faqplus](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-faqplus)